# jQuery selector unable to find table row class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given an array of strings returned from an sql query, I am appending the data as rows into my html table via javascript:

```
  loadUsers: function()
  { .
    .
    .
    function displayUsersOnTable(response)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++)
      {
        var contact = response.results[i];
        var $newRow = $('<tr class="user-row">' +
            '<td>' + contact.full_name + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + contact.email + '</td>' +
            '</tr>')
            .data('user', contact);

        $userTableBody.append($newRow);
      }
    }
  }
```

Inside a different function that is called *after* loadUsers is called, I have this:

```
$('.user-row').click( function() {
  window.alert("CLICKED");
});
```

When I run my site it won't register the click event. If I select the classes from my table row or table header it runs fine. I suspect the problem involves the fact that the table rows are dynamically generated. When I inspect element everything is in place. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.user-row', function() {
  window.alert("CLICKED");
});
```